# Unable to type text after a number if swype is activated

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I face a problem with my mobile website ruining with jQuery Mobile.

It seems that if the user browse from an android device with Swype is activated, he cannot enter a letter after a number.

For example, if the user wants to type "123hello", the "123" will work well and as soon as he tries to enter the "h", the h appear and then disappear instantly.

I have this problem only with my pages using jQuery Mobile framework, and there is no problem if Swype is disabled.
So I guess that it's something between jQuery Mobile and Swype.